# how to convert likes count in php

Tags: php

Assuming I have the code below in **PHP**

```
<?php 
$thousands_likes = 1100;
$millions_likes = 2100000;

?>
```

how do I convert it to something like

1.1k likes or 2.1M likes as case may be.

Comment: If >= 1000000 then / 1000000 and add M, If >= 1000 then / 1000 and add K, etc.

Comment: I now understand the logic.Can you update your response so that I can accept it as the best  solution. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something simple based on just millions and thousands:

```
if($likes >= 1000000) {
    $result = ($likes / 1000000) . 'M';
} elseif($likes >= 1000) {
    $result = ($likes / 1000) . 'K';
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe try creating a utility function for this kind of task? You can use plain math to calculate the suffix:

```
function human_readable_likes($likes): string
{
    $i = \floor(\log($likes, 1000));
    return \round($likes / 1000 ** $i, [0, 1, 2, 2, 2][$i]).' '.['', 'K', 'M', 'G', 'T'][$i];
}
```

but for your use case this might be too much.

Comment: @AbraCadaver Copied from SO and adapted to the use case here.

Comment: Ahhh, should probably link the answer.

Comment: I can't find it anymore. I had it copied into my project.